# What is the best full free alternative of Google Maps

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am developing an Android and IOS application that uses Map, Directions, Route, Duration etc. Using the map is the main function of the application. I was using google maps for test, when the number of request is low, everything works fine but when the number of requests increase google maps stops showing directions etc. So I was showing the map of google and using the directions of OpenStreetMap, which is not good-looking and unfortunately doesn't include traffic in duration
(ex. showing 10min to somewhere that I know it will take 20 min) but I had no choice. Now I want to move to a new map that is complete and more professional. So I was searching about a map that provides directions, duration s with traffic and also with low cost than Google maps services. Do you have any suggestions? 
What about creating my own map with OSM, does it take in charge traffic? 
Thank you for help.

Comment: Regarding OSM and traffic information: See this related question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/68579/is-there-any-osm-based-map-that-has-a-routing-service-which-includes-traffic

Answer (score 2):

There is no advanced maps like google map but you can try Open street map as an alternative.

Try it and enjoy...

Comment: Of course there is not, but google Maps API prices are too much expensive, I used OSM to get Direction and Duration but the issue is that the durations doesn't include traffic into routes. Is there any way to do it? what about MapBox?

Comment: Open street map is free

Comment: Please check OSM+ documentations